# Swift: Find value in array and return specific key

Tags: arrays, swift, string, dictionary, search

Im new to swift and would appreciate your help..

#### Problem:

In my future project I would love to look for a specific String in an Array and get **only the names** back who have this value in their hobbies Array.

#### My example:

```
struct Person {
var name: String
var hobbies:Set <String>
}

var persons: [Person]

persons = [

Person(name: "Steve", hobbies: ["PC", "PS4", "Gaming", "Basketball"]),
Person(name: "Max", hobbies: ["Gaming", "Xbox", "cooking", "PC"]),
Person(name: "Julia", hobbies: ["Soccer", "Tennis", "cooking", "Painting"])

]

var StringToSearch = "PC"
```

I would love to get only the names back who hobbies "PC" is. 
How can I iterate through my collection and get only the keys instead of the values back like in a dictionary?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

```
let result = persons.flatMap {
    $0.hobbies.contains(StringToSearch) ? $0.name : nil
}
```

Comment: Why flatMap and not filter?

Comment: There's more than one way to skin the cat. `flatMap` acts as a nil-filter. `contains` acts as the hobby-check. And the requirement is "only the names back"

Comment: Interesting, I'll check it out

Comment: I like this solution.  Unlike the answers that combine `filter` + `map`, this makes a single pass over the data.

Comment: @AMomchilov Note that any `filter` can be unrolled into a `flatMap`, which essentially acts as a `filter` and `map` all in one function, and as vacawama says, allows you to do this all in a single iteration. Probably the most flexible higher level function that Swift offers (certainly my personal favourite ;)).

Comment: this solution the best cause it combine filter+map. But the more interest thing is: the result contain only non-nil values.

Comment: OK @HoaParis and originalUser2, we all like this answer.  So why does it have only one upvote?

Comment: @vacawama No idea, one of them is mine though :) I guess the lack of explanation is (understandably) holding people back, although it's the still the best solution to the problem.

Comment: @originaluser2, maybe someone has downvoted then?  I know of 3 upvotes.

Comment: @vacawama Yes, that appears to be the case (you can click on the score to see the vote breakdown) – although I couldn't say why. Lack of explanation on an otherwise spot-on answer isn't worthy of a downvote imo.

Comment: Someone downvoted my answer, out of vengeance I guess?

Comment: I'm agree with @originaluser2. `flatmap` is new in swift so a little bit of explication is perfect.

Comment: Could be the lack of explanation.  It wouldn't hurt to point out how flatMap works and why it is more efficient than `filter` + `map`.

Answer (score 3):

## Using [`filter(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641239-filter)

```
let stringToSearch = "PC"
let pcHobbiests = persons.filter { $0.hobbies.contains(stringToSearch) }
let pcHobbiestNames = persons.map { $0.name }
```

## Explaination

`filter(_:)` will iterate over elements of a `Sequence`, building up a new Array containing only those elements for which closure evaluates to true. In this instance, the closure checks if the `hobbies` `Array` of the currently iteration's `Person` contains `stringToSearch`.

You can then iterate over your pcHobbiests Array or use them as you please:

```
for pcHobbiest in pcHobbiests {
    print(pcHobbiest)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use filter + map to return name array of all people who have "PC" hobbies:

```
let nameArray = persons.filter{$0.hobbies.contains("PC")}.map{$0.name}
//return ["Steve", "Max"]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Using reduce

After `map`, `filter` and `flatMap` here's my solution with `reduce` :)

```
let names = persons.reduce([String]()) { (names, person) -> [String] in
    guard person.hobbies.contains(keyword) else { return names }
    return names + [person.name]
}
```

### One liner (but don't do it at home!)

And if your really want to write everything on 1 line...

```
let names = persons.reduce([String]()) { $0.0 + ($0.1.hobbies.contains(keyword) ? [$0.1.name] : []) }
```

Comment: ;) nice code with reduce on one line. I give a up-vote but I must say that `reduce` solution is not very easy to read and understand :|

Comment: @HoaParis: I totally agree but the other solutions were already taken :D

Answer (score 1):

Use Swift's for-in loop.

```
for pers in persons {
    if pers.hobbies.contains(StringToSearch) {
        nameOfPCGamer = pers.name
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is not building a list of names matching ALL the persons with a specific hobby. It is just saving the name for the last person with that hobby instead.

Comment: I was just showing how to get all of them.  Handling the data inside of the if statement up to whoever to figure out.

Answer (score -2):

You may use a loop, collect:

```
for p in persons {
  if p.hobbies.contains("PC") {
    // then you've got one!
  }
}
```

or you can use a more generic programming by filtering the array, thus obtaining an array of filtered content and iterating on it:

```
for p in persons.filter({$0.hoobies.contains("PC")}) {
  // got one...
}
```